# C#におけるListの要素に対するGCの扱いについて

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

現在、以下の環境でWindowsアプリを作成しています。

- フレームワーク: .NET Framework 4.5.2
- 言語: C#
- ターゲットPC: Windows10 x64

そこで、掲題の件について質問です。
以下の様なコードでタイマを登録しているのですが、どうも2,3時間程度稼働してからタイマが止まっているようなのです。
ガベージコレクタかな？と思ったのですが、「GC.KeepAlive()」とtimers変数にタイマインスタンスを登録しています。

```
using System.Timers;

public class TimerSample {
    private static List<Timer> timers = new List<Timer>();

    private static void schedule() {
        var timer = new Timer();
        GC.KeepAlive(timer);
        timers.Add(timer);
        // タイマの設定処理...
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

例えば、KeepAliveがうまく効いていないとしたときに、インスタンスの参照を維持する為に行った、timers変数（List）へのタイマインスタンスはGC回避に有効でしょうか。
Listの要素については参照されているとみなされずGCされてしまうでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GC.KeepAlive`はインスタンスの寿命を`KeepAlive`メソッド呼び出しまで保証するものですので、事前に呼ぶのは誤りです。

一方`List<T>`に登録されているインスタンスは`List<T>`自体が参照されている限り有効です。この場合は`static`フィールドですので、基本的にはアプリケーション終了まで参照され続けるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！`KeepAlive`の使い方が誤っていたのですね。`AutoReset`が`true`のタイマについては`KeepAlive`はどのタイミングで呼ぶべきなのでしょうか。`Elapsed`に指定したメソッドの最後でしょうか。それともコール不要でしょうか。

Comment: @EarleyJP この例だと`GC.KeepAlive`は不要ですね。`AutoReset`が`true`ならば特に処理は必要ないのではないでしょうか。`false`であれば`Elapsed`イベントで`timers`から削除すべきですが。

Comment: 迅速なコメントありがとうございます！これについてはご教示頂いた通りに実装してみます！